# android development: how does my intent / icon get added to user's list like other social media in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, share, social-networking

I would like to allow users to highlight text and post it to my web site.
Is there a way to create an Android Intent running as a service which will show up on the social media / share list that appears in the Android system?

You know, when the user selects a picture and then the three dotted share icon appears and gives a list?  How can I get my application's intent and icon added to the list just as the Twitter, FB etc. ones that show up?

Comment: You don't need a service for that. You can start from here: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Comment: @PrerakSola Can you make that an answer so I can choose it as the answer.  This is exactly what I was searching for, but couldn't get a good google search that would bring something like that back before? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive data from an external application in your application vis `Share` functionality, you need to create an activity in your application which will accept the incoming data. Add the following details in `AndroidManifest.xml` for the Activity which will accept the data:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So , now if any application, shares a single image, your application will be visible in the list, and if the user selects your application, `ui.MyActivity` activity will be launched. You can change or add multiple `mimeType` as per your requirement.

Also, you can add/change `action` as `MULTIPLE_SEND` to receive multiple shared files.

Once this is done, in `onCreate()` method of your activity, you can fetch the data in the following manner:

```
void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    // Get intent, action and MIME type
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    //Play with the data, as per your need
    ...
}
```

You can get more details regarding this, in the [Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)